# Quadrado perfeito, não tão perfeito assim

Tags: c, operadores

Preciso saber se a soma de dois números é um quadrado perfeito,
pensei em somar os dois e tirar a raiz e depois verificar se o resto da divisão por 1 é maior que zero, só que o operador (%) só trabalha com inteiros e sqrt não me devolve em int, alguém tem uma ideia melhor ou sabe como posso construir minha própria função MOD?

```
if(sqrt(a+b)%1==0) ...
```

Comment: Qual é a linguagem?

Comment: estou usando a liguagem c

Comment: `int tentativa = sqrt(valor); if (tentativa * tentativa == valor) /* quadrado perfeito */;`

Answer (score 1):

```c
int quadperfeito(int n)
{
    return (sqrt(n)-((int)sqrt(n)) == 0);
}

int somaEhQuadperfeito(int m, int n)
{
    return quadperfeito(m+n);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma possibilidade é fazer uma busca binária. Assim você não precisa de usar float.

```
unsigned intSqrt(int N){
    // invariante: lo*lo <= N < hi*hi
    unsigned lo = 0;     
    unsigned hi = 1<<16;
    while(hi - lo > 1){
        unsigned mid = (lo + hi)/2;
        unsigned mid2 = mid*mid;
        if( mid2 < N ){
            lo = mid;
        }else if(mid2 == N){
            return mid;
        }else{ // N < mid2
            hi = mid;
        }
    }
    return lo;
}

int quadradoPerfeito(unsigned N){
   int x = intSqrt(N);
   return x*x == N;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Encontrei uma solução:

```
int raiz_int = sqrt(a+b); 
double raiz_double = sqrt(a+b); 
if (raiz_int == raiz_double) ... ;
else ...
```

Não é a melhor maneira mas serve